# Number plate recognition using android

Tags: java, android, image-processing, automatic-license-plate-recognition

I was wondering if anybody new of a way that I could use of scanning a registration plate on a car and then adding that number to a string inside java? I have been looking around a bit and came across this

https://github.com/SandroMachado/openalpr-android

But I'm not sure that it's exactly what I am looking for?

Anybody know of anything that might be of use? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Google has recently released Mobile Vision API for text recognition from images. You can take a picture from camera and then use this API to get your desired result. Link - https://developers.google.com/vision/text-overview